# Spree "Not a number" error during checkout when we try to add Products into carts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, spree

From normal checkout i'm just trying to remove following steps,
my order_decorator.rb looks like this.

```
remove_checkout_step :delivery
remove_checkout_step :address
remove_checkout_step :payment

def confirmation_required?
true
end
```

Whenever i try to add products quantity and hit the add to cart button  i get the above error and i'm being redirected to product/show page. with the message shown in screenshot.

My gemfile has:

> gem 'capistrano' gem 'rvm-capistrano' gem 'spree', github:
>   'spree/spree', branch: '2-0-stable' gem 'spree_gateway', :git =>
>   'https://github.com/spree/spree_gateway.git', :branch => "2-0-stable"
>   gem 'spree_auth_devise', :github => 'spree/spree_auth_devise', :branch
>   => '2-0-stable' gem 'spree_i18n', :github => 'spree/spree_i18n', :branch => '2-0-stable'

Any clue?

[image]

Comment: I just tried the same example using a Spree sandbox (v2.0.5) and didn't have any issues.  Are you able to replicate these issues on a Spree sandbox?  You may be having an issue with one of the other customizations you've made to your application.

Comment: Looking at the code, I think the issue is that you are removing the payment step and confirmation step is for the payment as described in the method  confirmation_required? core/app/models/spree/order.rb with true.  Some variable required by payment ( not configured by you as you do not need payment) is failing.  Remove this override def confirmation_required? and check, it should throw a better error. In short, give false for the confirmation step as this is payment confirmation step or include payment. I am new to Spree, so I am not 100% sure too.